# C++ OpenCV - Find biggest object in an webcam stream and sort it by size

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

My goal is to find the biggest contour of a captured webcam frame, then after it's found, find its size and determine either to be rejected or accepted.

Just to explain the objetive of this project, i am currently working for a Hygiene product's Manufacturer. There we have, in total, 6 workers that are responsible for sorting the defective soap bars out of the production line. So in order to gain this workforce for other activities, i am trying to write an algorithm to "replace" their eyes.

I've tried several methods along the way (findcontours, SimpleBlobDetection, Canny, Object tracking), but the problem that i've been facing is that i can't seem to find a way to effectively find the biggest object in a webcam image, find its size and then determine to either discard or accept it.

Below follows my newest code to find the biggest contour in an webcam stream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{

    Mat src;
    Mat imgGrayScale;
    Mat imgCanny;
    Mat imgBlurred;

    /// Load source image 
    VideoCapture capWebcam(0);

    if (capWebcam.isOpened() == false)
    {
        cout << "Não foi possível abrir webcam!" << endl;

        return(0);

    }

    while (capWebcam.isOpened())
    {

        bool blnframe = capWebcam.read(src);

        if (!blnframe || src.empty())
        {
            cout << "Erro! Frame não lido!\n";
            break;
        }


        int largest_area = 0;

        int largest_contour_index = 0;

        Rect bounding_rect;

        Mat thr(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC1);

        Mat dst(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar::all(0));

        cvtColor(src, imgGrayScale, CV_BGR2GRAY); //Convert to gray

        GaussianBlur(imgGrayScale, imgBlurred, Size(5, 5), 1.8);

        Canny(imgBlurred, imgCanny, 45, 90); //Threshold the gray

        vector<vector<Point>> contours; // Vector for storing contour
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
        findContours(imgCanny, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); // Find the contours in the image
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) // iterate through each contour. 
        {

            double a = contourArea(contours[i], false);  //  Find the area of contour
            if (a > largest_area) 
            {
                largest_area = a;
                largest_contour_index = i;                //Store the index of largest contour
                bounding_rect = boundingRect(contours[i]); // Find the bounding rectangle for biggest contour
            }

        }

        Scalar color(255, 255, 255);
        drawContours(dst, contours, largest_contour_index, color, CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy); // Draw the largest contour using previously stored index.
        rectangle(src, bounding_rect, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0);

        imshow("src", src);
        imshow("largest Contour", dst);

        waitKey(27);

    }

    return(0);
}
```

And here are the results windows that the program generates and the image of the object that i want to detect and sort.

[image]

[image]

Thank you all in advance for any clues on how to achieve my goal.

Comment: The title of this question is rather confusing -- either there's one "biggest" object, or there are multiple with the same size. What does sorting that by size achieve?

Comment: I see that...Well actually it's supposed to have more packages (like the one displayed above) in the scene. My goal is to calculate multiples objects by its size and then determine to either discard it or accept it into the process.

Comment: But first, to be able to calculate the area/size, i thought that would be best to find an object and then calculate...i don't know...i am kinda lost at this point...i am really looking for any directions right now!

Comment: You actualy get a good contour of that logo. Is your objective to detect the size of that logo in multiple packages within the same frame?

Comment: Actually my objective is to get the external area of the packages (not the logo), contour it, calculate its areas and then execute a condition to either reject it or accept it. The problem is that i am not beeing able to find the external contour of the object, only the logo...other thing is that the object has to be almost frozen in front of the camera in order to get detected...i wonder if there is a way to detect it faster...